# Change outline for invalid required properties on Edge

Tags: html, css, microsoft-edge

So I have a standard input box:

```
 <input required="required" />
```

And here is my css to only apply the styling when the required inputs are invalid:

```
input:required:invalid{   
    outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

But this is being applied immediately in edge.

Does anyone know how to only apply this css when the required input is invalid?

Comment: By "immediately", you mean when the input box is still empty? In that case I'd say the browser has got it right. An empty value is invalid if the value is required!

Comment: Yes, i mean when the page loads. It is right, in a way, but I want the effect only to be added when I submit the form. Btw how's Kryten doing these days?

Comment: then you can't have that css on page load, just use a validator on submit to add a class that would make it recognize its invalid

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a css selector that's only applied after a submit. Maybe you can use a `:target` pseudo-class: Something like `<body id="page">` combined with `<form action="#page">`, then you can write `:target input:blabla` in your css.

Comment: @MrLister Okay thanks, I'm guessing your name isn't from red dwart then?

Comment: @Andrew Yes it is, but I couldn't think of a corny comeback.